# upload apk to market (android)

Tags: android, google-play

I am new in Android. I have develop an app. And now want to upload it to Androit market.
Have you got a good tutorial for upload my apk on this market.

Thanks!

Comment: Googling "Android market tutorial" brings up dozens. The first few look perfect.

Comment: Did you search before posting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you meet [all these requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html), and then follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html) or [this](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/publishing-your-app-to-the-android-market-a-noobs-guide/) or even [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/).

Comment: Thnaks for link! Good tutorial! I have uploaded all.